# Why/How can javascript access to local variables when I use "this"?

Tags: javascript

when I define "Car" like below,

```
var Car = function(m) {
    var model = m;
    function getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    return {
        getModel : getModel
    }
};
```

and I created an object like this `var c1 = new Car("qwer");`

in this case, I can't access to model directly, only by closure.

```
(console.log(c1.model); => undefined)

(console.log (c1.getModel ()); => qwer)
```

but when I define "Car" like below,

```
var Car = function(m) {
    var model = m;
    function getModel() {
        return this.model;
    }
    return {
        getModel : getModel
    }
};
```

and I created object `var c2 = new Car("asdg");`

in this case, I can not access to model directly ,
 but also by closure.

```
(console.log(c2.model)  =>  undefined)

(console.log (c2.getModel () => undefined)
```

can u tell me why this happens?

Comment: Because `this` refers to the instance and there is no `model` instance variable...? `model` is a *local variable*, essentially private and not on the instance. Also, returning from a constructor does nothing... the return statement is ignored because constructors aren't supposed to return anything.

Comment: I'm sure there's a post somewhere that explains `this`

Comment: [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work/3127440#3127440)

Comment: That _model_ is a local variable, it is not a property of the object created.

Answer (score 1):

In first case when you do:

```
(console.log (c1.getModel ()); => qwer)
```

You get "qwer" because getModel() function can read variable `model` from `outer scope`.

However, in second case, in the line `return this.model;`, `this` is dynamically bound to `c2` object and c2 object doesn't have `model`. All c2 has is the function `getModel()`. You can achieve the desired result in the following way:

```js
var Car = function(m) {
  this.model = m;
  this.getModel = function() {
    return this.model;
  }
  //return {
  //    getModel: getModel
  //}
};
var c2 = new Car("asdg");
console.log(c2.getModel());
```

Note that even above solution is less than ideal because, functions should ideally be attached to constructor function's `prototype` object. So, I would suggest you do some looking around stack overflow a bit and you would get some more insight.